# ExoPlayer replay button breaks when adding an onPlayerStateChanged listener that causes recomposition in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I've created an ExoPlayer instance and a button for the user to press if they want the video to be replayed. The button works but only during the playback of the video; when the video completes playback the button no longer works. I have code that runs to show a button when the video completes playback that I think is responsible for breaking this replay button but I can't figure out why!

This is the same issue I'm experiencing in another question I've posted about, but I've had some thoughts as to what's causing the issue hence another post.

I run the code below in the `onCreate()` method to make sure that the code is run only once when the Activity is started:

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current

val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .build()
        .also { exoPlayer ->
            val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.xxxxxx))
                    .build()
            exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
            exoPlayer.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
            exoPlayer.addListener(playerEventListener)
            exoPlayer.prepare()
        }

DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(factory = {
            StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
                hideController()
                useController = false
                player = exoPlayer
            }
    })) {
    onDispose { exoPlayer.release() }
}
```

Then here is the code to create the replay button. This is also run in the `onCreate()` method.

```kotlin
Button(onClick = {                             
    exoPlayer.seekTo(0)
    exoPlayer.play() 
    },){
    Text(
       text = "replay",
       fontSize = 18.sp,
       modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
       textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
}
```

Now this code works while playback is in progress, but when the video ends the button no longer works and I can just see the final frame of the video.

I've found that this might be something to do with the viewModel method from the method in my `exoPlayer.addListener(playerEventListener)` line:

```kotlin
    private val playerEventListener = object : Player.Listener
    {
        override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int)
        {
            super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
            // when the video ends, make the button to move onto the next page appear
            if (playbackState==ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED)
            {
                viewModel.showNextButton()
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the code for the viewModel so that you can see the `viewModel.showNextButton()` method:

```kotlin
data class TutorialUiState(
        val showNextButton: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)
                          )

class TutorialViewModel(application: HDiagsApplication) : AndroidViewModel(application)
{
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(TutorialUiState())
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun showNextButton()
    {
        uiState.value.showNextButton.value = true
    }
}
```

When the `uiState.value.showNextButton.value` is set to true, another button on the UI is shown, here is the code for the button:

```kotlin
val uiState by remember {
    mutableStateOf(viewModel.uiState.value)
}

if (viewModel.showButton.value)
{
   ButtonCore(text = "Begin test") {
       startActivity(Intent(this@TutorialJetpack, ParadigmControllerJetpack::class.java))
   }
}
```

My current working theory is that this value change in the `viewModel.showNextButton()` method causes a recomposition which is breaking exoplayer, but how do I show a new button when the video ends without causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had forgotten to use `remember`. This meant that a new player was being created each time a recomposition occurred.

In my code:

```
val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer
    .Builder(context)
    .build()
    .also { exoPlayer ->
    val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
}
```

should be replaced with...

```
val exoPlayer = remember {
    ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
        .build()
        .also { exoPlayer ->
          val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
         }
```

So that this doesn't occur!

This fixed my issue and I hope it helped someone out there too :)